# When a function contains a sequence, and how to find the function's limit?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. Find the limit

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1+a_n \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

It's kind intuitive that the answer is 1, but clearly I can't just say that the limits equal $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} 1^n = 1$.

I feel like I should let $y =(1+a_n \frac{x}{n})^n $. Then take $log$ so that $log(y) = nlog(1+a_n \frac{x}{n})$ But L'hopital doesn't apply here either

Comment: hint :$$n\log(1+a_n \frac{x}{n}) = \dfrac{\log(1+a_n \frac{x}{n})}{1/n}$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 so we apply limit, and using L'hopital rule. But know do I take the derivative of a sequence?

Comment: You definitely can't say it is like $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n$, because that same reasoning would show that $\lim (1+x/n)^n$ is $1$, when it is $e^x$. You need that $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n \to 0$ then, no matter how big $x$ is, for any $n$ big enough we have $|a_n x|\leq \varepsilon$, hence:
$$\left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\right)e^{-\varepsilon}\leq\left(1+\frac{a_n x}{n}\right)^n \leq e^{\varepsilon}.$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number, the claim follows by squeezing.

Comment: Could you explain  why is $$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} e^{\epsilon} = 0? $$ I know that  $\epsilon$ can be arbitrary small positive, but why does it have anything to do with $ n \to \infty ?$

Comment: @ElleryLai: I have not stated that. The point is the following: given any positive $\varepsilon$, the sequence given by $b_n=\left(1+\frac{a_n x}{n}\right)^n$, for any $n$ big enough, is between the LHS and the RHS of what I wrote, hence: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} b_n = \color{red}{1}.$$

Comment: I couldn't figure out why is that $$\left(1+\frac{a_n x}{n}\right)^n \leq e^{\varepsilon}.$$ ?? because of the limit definition of limit?

Comment: @ElleryLai: because for any positive $A$, the sequence $$(1+A/n)^n $$ is an increasing sequence that converges towards $e^A$. Basic fact.

Comment: Since $-\epsilon < a_{n}x < \epsilon$ the inequality should be like $$\left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^{n} < \left(1 + \frac{a_{n}x}{n}\right)^{n} < \left(1 + \frac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^{n}$$ and this would lead to $$e^{-\epsilon} \leq \left(1 + \frac{a_{n}x}{n}\right)^{n}\leq e^{\epsilon}$$ for sufficiently large values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Supose $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}=0$. Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x\cdot a_n=0$,
$$
                 \left( 
                       1+a_n\frac{x}{n}
                 \right)^{n}
=
      \left( 
             1+\frac{1}{n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}}
      \right)^n
=
         \left[
                 \left( 
                       1+\frac{1}{n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}}
                 \right)^{n\cdot\frac{1}{\color{red}{ x\cdot a_n}}}
         \right]^{\color{red}{ x\cdot a_n}}
$$
and $
\lim_{n\to \infty}
                 \left( 
                       1+\frac{1}{\color{blue}{n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}}}
                 \right)^{\color{blue}{n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}}}=e
$. 
If $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}=0$ then
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}
                  \left[
                 \left( 
                       1+\frac{1}{n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}}
                 \right)^{n\cdot\frac{1}{\color{red}{ x\cdot a_n}}}
         \right]^{\color{red}{ x\cdot a_n}}
=\ldots =e^0=1
$$
The case $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{ x\cdot a_n}=L\in\mathbb{R}$ is trivial.

Comment: why is that $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{xa_n} = 0 ?$

Comment: also, for you last part, you seem to use  if $$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(n) = l$$ and $$ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g(n) = m$$, then $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(n)^{g(n)} = l^m  $$. I'm not sure if this is one of the limit properties

Comment: @Ellery If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{x\cdot a_n}=L\neq 0$ and $L\in\mathbb{R}$ then the question is trivial. In your secont coment you are right. I hope helped you.

Comment: @ElleryLai Do not intend to exhaust all cases to be analyzed. In the case of home work, is not purpose of this site provide full  answers.